# Make procedure in Scheme by lambda

Tags: scheme, sicp

I am learning Scheme by '*Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs*'

In Chapter 1.3.2 **Constructing Procedures Using lambda**.

I understood lambda like this.

The value to match the lambda is written outside the parenthesis of the lambda.

`((lambda (x) (+ x 4) 4)  ; (x) is matched to 4, result is 8`

But in *SICP*, another example code is different.

The code is :

```lisp
(define (sum x y) (+ x y))

(define (pi-sum a b)
  (sum (lambda (x) (/ 1.0 (* x (+ x 3))))
        a
        (lambda (x) (+ x 4))
        b
         ))

(pi-sum 3 6)
```

I think if `(lambda (x) (/ 1.0 (* x (+ x 3))))` want match to `a`, `lambda` and `a` must bound by parenthesis.

But in example code, don't use parenthesis.

When I run this code, error is occurs.

error is this :

```
***'sum: expects only 2 arguments, but found 4'***
```

When I use more parenthesis like this :

```lisp
(define (sum x y) (+ x y))

(define (pi-sum a b)
  (sum ((lambda (x) (/ 1.0 (* x (+ x 3))))
        a)
        ((lambda (x) (+ x 4))
        b)
         ))

(pi-sum 2 6) ; result is 10.1
```

Code is run.

I'm confused because of *SICP*'s example code.

Am I right on the principle of `lambda`?

If I am right, why *SICP* write like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It says to use the sum from 1.3.1. On page 77 (actually starting on 77 and ending on 78) it looks like this:

```
(define (sum term a next b)
  (if (> a b)
      0
      (+ (term a)
         (sum term (next a) next b))))
```

As you can see it looks a lot different from your `sum` that just adds two number together. You also had a typo in `pi-sum`:

```
(define (pi-sum a b)
  (sum (lambda (x) (/ 1.0 (* x (+ x 2)))) ; multiplied by 2, not 3!
       a
       (lambda (x) (+ x 4))
       b))

(* 8 (pi-sum 1 1000))
; ==> 3.139592655589783
```

So the point here is that you can pass lambdas instead of named procedures. Since `(define (name . args) body ...)` is just syntax sugar for `(define name (lambda args body ...))` passing `(lambda args body ...)` instead of defining it and pass a name is just an equal refactoring.

Parentheses around a variable `(+)` or a lambda `((lambda args body ...))` calls whatever procedure the operator expression evaluates. It is not what you want since you pass procedures to be used by `sum` as an abstraction. `sum` can do multiplications or any number of things based on what you pass. in `sum` `term` is the procedure `(lambda (x) (/ 1.0 (* x (+ x 2))))` and you see it calls it as apart of its code.